# How to temporarily turn off certain unix cronjobs using a script

Tags: unix

I have few cronjobs running everyday Mon-friday.At times during holidays, i turn them off manually so that it doesnt run that day and turn back on the next day.

Is there a way to automate this using a script

Comment: btw this might be better off on serverfault

Answer (score 8):

Ignacio was suggesting something like this in your crontab:

```
 31 1 * * *    [ -f /var/run/cron-holiday ] || /usr/local/bin/whatever-command
```

then at the start of a holiday weekend, as root:

```
 # touch /var/run/cron-holiday
```

and on Monday:

```
 # rm /var/run/cron-holiday
```

This is nice and simple but does have the drawback that if you forget to delete the file, your cronscripts will never run again, which could be bad.

An alternative is to have a file listing holiday dates and do something like this:

```
31 1 * * *   grep -q `date -I` /etc/cron-holidays || whatever-command-here
```

where the /etc/cron-holidays file contains lines like

```
2011-04-01
2011-12-25
```

etc

Comment: Is the file has to be created in "/var/run/"?

Comment: @TrueBlue10, no it could be anywhere, for instance in /root or even owned by some other user.

Answer (score 2):

Make the cron jobs look for a flag (file) under `/var/run`, then write an initscript that sets or resets that flag.

Comment: ignacio...i am total unix noob..could you give me an example of the script.